# Working Example of D3 JS BubbleChart with JSON

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So this example below is a very basic example I've cobbled together after a lot of playing around with D3 and their poor documentation, but it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="module">

import * as d3 from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7/+esm";

const svg = BubbleChart([["Hello", 10], ["World", 20]]);
document.body.appendChild(svg);

// Copyright 2021 Observable, Inc.
// Released under the ISC license.
// https://observablehq.com/@d3/bubble-chart
function BubbleChart(data, {
  name = ([x]) => x, // alias for label
  label = name, // given d in data, returns text to display on the bubble
  value = ([, y]) => y, // given d in data, returns a quantitative size
  group, // given d in data, returns a categorical value for color
  title, // given d in data, returns text to show on hover
  link, // given a node d, its link (if any)
  linkTarget = "_blank", // the target attribute for links, if any
  width = 640, // outer width, in pixels
  height = width, // outer height, in pixels
  padding = 3, // padding between circles
  margin = 1, // default margins
  marginTop = margin, // top margin, in pixels
  marginRight = margin, // right margin, in pixels
  marginBottom = margin, // bottom margin, in pixels
  marginLeft = margin, // left margin, in pixels
  groups, // array of group names (the domain of the color scale)
  colors = d3.schemeTableau10, // an array of colors (for groups)
  fill = "#ccc", // a static fill color, if no group channel is specified
  fillOpacity = 0.7, // the fill opacity of the bubbles
  stroke, // a static stroke around the bubbles
  strokeWidth, // the stroke width around the bubbles, if any
  strokeOpacity, // the stroke opacity around the bubbles, if any
} = {}) {
  // Compute the values.
  const D = d3.map(data, d => d);
  const V = d3.map(data, value);
  const G = group == null ? null : d3.map(data, group);
  const I = d3.range(V.length).filter(i => V[i] > 0);

  // Unique the groups.
  if (G && groups === undefined) groups = I.map(i => G[i]);
  groups = G && new d3.InternSet(groups);

  // Construct scales.
  const color = G && d3.scaleOrdinal(groups, colors);

  // Compute labels and titles.
  const L = label == null ? null : d3.map(data, label);
  const T = title === undefined ? L : title == null ? null : d3.map(data, title);

  // Compute layout: create a 1-deep hierarchy, and pack it.
  const root = d3.pack()
      .size([width - marginLeft - marginRight, height - marginTop - marginBottom])
      .padding(padding)
    (d3.hierarchy({children: I})
      .sum(i => V[i]));

  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("viewBox", [-marginLeft, -marginTop, width, height])
      .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;")
      .attr("fill", "currentColor")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

  const leaf = svg.selectAll("a")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .join("a")
      .attr("xlink:href", link == null ? null : (d, i) => link(D[d.data], i, data))
      .attr("target", link == null ? null : linkTarget)
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);

  leaf.append("circle")
      .attr("stroke", stroke)
      .attr("stroke-width", strokeWidth)
      .attr("stroke-opacity", strokeOpacity)
      .attr("fill", G ? d => color(G[d.data]) : fill == null ? "none" : fill)
      .attr("fill-opacity", fillOpacity)
      .attr("r", d => d.r);

  if (T) leaf.append("title")
      .text(d => T[d.data]);

  if (L) {
    // A unique identifier for clip paths (to avoid conflicts).
    const uid = `O-${Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)}`;

    leaf.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", d => `${uid}-clip-${d.data}`)
      .append("circle")
        .attr("r", d => d.r);

    leaf.append("text")
        .attr("clip-path", d => `url(${new URL(`#${uid}-clip-${d.data}`, location)})`)
      .selectAll("tspan")
      .data(d => `${L[d.data]}`.split(/\n/g))
      .join("tspan")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", (d, i, D) => `${i - D.length / 2 + 0.85}em`)
        .attr("fill-opacity", (d, i, D) => i === D.length - 1 ? 0.7 : null)
        .text(d => d);
  }

  return Object.assign(svg.node(), {scales: {color}});
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is great. But the data source is very JavaScript specific with the multi-dimensional JavaScript Array at the top.

I want to use data type such as JSON i.e. a basic JSON Array

```
[
   {
      "Key":"Hello",
      "Value":10
   },
   {
      "Key":"World",
      "Value":20
   }
]
```

I can't figure out how to do this. Every example from the official docs is to load a data.json type file. No-one is going to be going that in any real world example, all this data is going to be dynamic.

If I can figure out what the syntax is that I need, the rest should be easy. Just can't find any working examples of something which seems so basic.

I even tried something that (wishfully thinking) would work such as the below, but it didn't;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="module">

import * as d3 from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7/+esm";

const svg = BubbleChart(
                    [
                {
                    "Key" : "Hello", 
                    "Value" : 10
                }, 
                {
                    "Key" : "World", 
                    "Value" : 20
                }
            ]);


document.body.appendChild(svg);

// Copyright 2021 Observable, Inc.
// Released under the ISC license.
// https://observablehq.com/@d3/bubble-chart
function BubbleChart(data, {
  name = ([x]) => x, // alias for label
  label = name, // given d in data, returns text to display on the bubble
  value = ([, y]) => y, // given d in data, returns a quantitative size
  group, // given d in data, returns a categorical value for color
  title, // given d in data, returns text to show on hover
  link, // given a node d, its link (if any)
  linkTarget = "_blank", // the target attribute for links, if any
  width = 640, // outer width, in pixels
  height = width, // outer height, in pixels
  padding = 3, // padding between circles
  margin = 1, // default margins
  marginTop = margin, // top margin, in pixels
  marginRight = margin, // right margin, in pixels
  marginBottom = margin, // bottom margin, in pixels
  marginLeft = margin, // left margin, in pixels
  groups, // array of group names (the domain of the color scale)
  colors = d3.schemeTableau10, // an array of colors (for groups)
  fill = "#ccc", // a static fill color, if no group channel is specified
  fillOpacity = 0.7, // the fill opacity of the bubbles
  stroke, // a static stroke around the bubbles
  strokeWidth, // the stroke width around the bubbles, if any
  strokeOpacity, // the stroke opacity around the bubbles, if any
} = {}) {
  // Compute the values.
  const D = d3.map(data, d => d);
  const V = d3.map(data, value);
  const G = group == null ? null : d3.map(data, group);
  const I = d3.range(V.length).filter(i => V[i] > 0);

  // Unique the groups.
  if (G && groups === undefined) groups = I.map(i => G[i]);
  groups = G && new d3.InternSet(groups);

  // Construct scales.
  const color = G && d3.scaleOrdinal(groups, colors);

  // Compute labels and titles.
  const L = label == null ? null : d3.map(data, label);
  const T = title === undefined ? L : title == null ? null : d3.map(data, title);

  // Compute layout: create a 1-deep hierarchy, and pack it.
  const root = d3.pack()
      .size([width - marginLeft - marginRight, height - marginTop - marginBottom])
      .padding(padding)
    (d3.hierarchy({children: I})
      .sum(i => V[i]));

  const svg = d3.create("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("viewBox", [-marginLeft, -marginTop, width, height])
      .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;")
      .attr("fill", "currentColor")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

  const leaf = svg.selectAll("a")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .join("a")
      .attr("xlink:href", link == null ? null : (d, i) => link(D[d.data], i, data))
      .attr("target", link == null ? null : linkTarget)
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);

  leaf.append("circle")
      .attr("stroke", stroke)
      .attr("stroke-width", strokeWidth)
      .attr("stroke-opacity", strokeOpacity)
      .attr("fill", G ? d => color(G[d.data]) : fill == null ? "none" : fill)
      .attr("fill-opacity", fillOpacity)
      .attr("r", d => d.r);

  if (T) leaf.append("title")
      .text(d => T[d.data]);

  if (L) {
    // A unique identifier for clip paths (to avoid conflicts).
    const uid = `O-${Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)}`;

    leaf.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", d => `${uid}-clip-${d.data}`)
      .append("circle")
        .attr("r", d => d.r);

    leaf.append("text")
        .attr("clip-path", d => `url(${new URL(`#${uid}-clip-${d.data}`, location)})`)
      .selectAll("tspan")
      .data(d => `${L[d.data]}`.split(/\n/g))
      .join("tspan")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", (d, i, D) => `${i - D.length / 2 + 0.85}em`)
        .attr("fill-opacity", (d, i, D) => i === D.length - 1 ? 0.7 : null)
        .text(d => d);
  }

  return Object.assign(svg.node(), {scales: {color}});
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here if you know D3?

Official support places are useless at providing working examples and documentation is abysmal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by changing three lines from the original code:

- `name = obj => obj.Key`
- `const D = d3.map(data, d => d.Key);`
- `const V = d3.map(data, d => d.Value);`

Full working javascript:

```js
import * as d3 from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7/+esm";

const input = [
  {
    Key: "Hello",
    Value: 10
  },
  {
    Key: "World",
    Value: 20
  },
  {
    Key: "Foo",
    Value: 5
  },
  {
    Key: "Bar",
    Value: 30
  }
];

const svg = BubbleChart(input);
document.body.appendChild(svg);

// Copyright 2021 Observable, Inc.
// Released under the ISC license.
// https://observablehq.com/@d3/bubble-chart
function BubbleChart(
  data,
  {
    name = (obj) => obj.Key, // alias for label
    label = name, // given d in data, returns text to display on the bubble
    //value = ([, y]) => y, // given d in data, returns a quantitative size
    group, // given d in data, returns a categorical value for color
    title, // given d in data, returns text to show on hover
    link, // given a node d, its link (if any)
    linkTarget = "_blank", // the target attribute for links, if any
    width = 640, // outer width, in pixels
    height = width, // outer height, in pixels
    padding = 3, // padding between circles
    margin = 1, // default margins
    marginTop = margin, // top margin, in pixels
    marginRight = margin, // right margin, in pixels
    marginBottom = margin, // bottom margin, in pixels
    marginLeft = margin, // left margin, in pixels
    groups, // array of group names (the domain of the color scale)
    colors = d3.schemeTableau10, // an array of colors (for groups)
    fill = "#ccc", // a static fill color, if no group channel is specified
    fillOpacity = 0.7, // the fill opacity of the bubbles
    stroke, // a static stroke around the bubbles
    strokeWidth, // the stroke width around the bubbles, if any
    strokeOpacity // the stroke opacity around the bubbles, if any
  } = {}
) {
  // Compute the values.
  const D = d3.map(data, (d) => d.Key);
  const V = d3.map(data, (d) => d.Value);
  const G = group == null ? null : d3.map(data, group);
  const I = d3.range(V.length).filter((i) => V[i] > 0);

  // Unique the groups.
  if (G && groups === undefined) groups = I.map((i) => G[i]);
  groups = G && new d3.InternSet(groups);

  // Construct scales.
  const color = G && d3.scaleOrdinal(groups, colors);

  // Compute labels and titles.
  const L = label == null ? null : d3.map(data, label);
  const T =
    title === undefined ? L : title == null ? null : d3.map(data, title);

  // Compute layout: create a 1-deep hierarchy, and pack it.
  const root = d3
    .pack()
    .size([width - marginLeft - marginRight, height - marginTop - marginBottom])
    .padding(padding)(d3.hierarchy({ children: I }).sum((i) => V[i]));

  const svg = d3
    .create("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", [-marginLeft, -marginTop, width, height])
    .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;")
    .attr("fill", "currentColor")
    .attr("font-size", 10)
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

  const leaf = svg
    .selectAll("a")
    .data(root.leaves())
    .join("a")
    .attr(
      "xlink:href",
      link == null ? null : (d, i) => link(D[d.data], i, data)
    )
    .attr("target", link == null ? null : linkTarget)
    .attr("transform", (d) => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);

  leaf
    .append("circle")
    .attr("stroke", stroke)
    .attr("stroke-width", strokeWidth)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", strokeOpacity)
    .attr("fill", G ? (d) => color(G[d.data]) : fill == null ? "none" : fill)
    .attr("fill-opacity", fillOpacity)
    .attr("r", (d) => d.r);

  if (T) leaf.append("title").text((d) => T[d.data]);

  if (L) {
    // A unique identifier for clip paths (to avoid conflicts).
    const uid = `O-${Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)}`;

    leaf
      .append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", (d) => `${uid}-clip-${d.data}`)
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", (d) => d.r);

    leaf
      .append("text")
      .attr(
        "clip-path",
        (d) => `url(${new URL(`#${uid}-clip-${d.data}`, location)})`
      )
      .selectAll("tspan")
      .data((d) => `${L[d.data]}`.split(/\n/g))
      .join("tspan")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", (d, i, D) => `${i - D.length / 2 + 0.85}em`)
      .attr("fill-opacity", (d, i, D) => (i === D.length - 1 ? 0.7 : null))
      .text((d) => d);
  }

  return Object.assign(svg.node(), { scales: { color } });
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: sceenshot of bubble chart]

Comment: How did you work that out @Peter F? The naming conventions of this script are so cryptic and I can't see how you have managed to connect the dots?

Comment: I mean, it works, and I've managed to move a step forwards, so thanks very much for that. Just can't figure out how you knew to do that (and how I can learn to connect the dots that you have).

Comment: Basically I've worked with D3 before a bit :) The names of variables in the example you found are evil. I recognized that `name`, `D`, and `V` looked like "accessor" or "extractor" functions", which means they get called on each item in the array to get the name, data(?), or value(?). I changed the accessor functions to work on an object instead of an array. I like this website for learning: https://www.d3indepth.com As you have probably discovered, the official D3 tutorials and examples are unhelpful.

Comment: Thanks @Peter F - I'll take a look at that site for learning more. And glad to see that site is for recent V7 rather than most examples online for V2,3,4 etc. which are useless. Yes, I agree, the official D3 tutorials are abysmal. To the point I've already been blocked from their official support channels for asking too many (about 3....) questions asking for help and basic working examples - it's a joke. Guess Mike Bostok didn't quite like the constructive criticism. Glad I'm not the only one who feels this way. Are there any other high quality resources you can recommend on D3?

Comment: In addition - That evil code example, as you describe it, was found was from.... the official D3 docs. It's no wonder why there is not a very active community and wider usage of the tech compared to other chart visualisation technologies. Such a shame really as it's probably one of the more powerful bits of tech.

Comment: I do not know of any other high-quality resources for D3 version 7. (But I have not looked for them)

Comment: I have thought of another tool for learning D3: using TypeScript is illuminating for some cases. How to get started: https://github.com/Lemoncode/d3js-typescript-examples In VS Code, you can right-click on a D3 function then choose "Go to type definition" to see documentation. Or you can view the type definitions, which include documentation, without installing anything. For example: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-scale/v3/index.d.ts

Comment: Thanks @Peter F - I'm more used to strongly typed languages like Java - I find JavaScript a pain in the a***e with it's fluffy nature. I've just had a quick skim of those links, but too much messing about trying to get things working for my liking. I just don't have time for fiddling about trying to get the thing to work. Tried to look at that DefinitelyTyped thing (what is that BTW? Seems some gigantic wrapper trying to turn JavaScript into pseudo Java) - but couldn't get the full list to load and noticed D3 was V3.0 and couldn't find V7 without cloning locally and messing about so gave up.